# integrating PayPal gateway with html page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, paypal

I am using codeigniter and html and want to integrate PayPal with my HTML page. I have already pasted the button on my page but am unable to redirect to the page for payment through credit/debit card by clicking on the button.Please help

My Code is

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif"    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"   height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Did the page redirect anywhere at all when the button is clicked?

Comment: You left out the "<" at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @ CarbonBasedLifeform : the page redirects to itself does not move forward...

Answer (score 0):

Happy new year. You can use this library for integrate paypal https://github.com/phpfour/php-payment[1](https://github.com/phpfour/php-payment)

Comment: i am using codeigniter for developing the website..can u help me integrating the files with codeigniter? Happy New Year to u too...

Comment: please follow the codeigniter guideline for usage external library. that's very simple.

Comment: the above code gives the same output...does not redirect to the paypal gateway

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your action attribute in the form tag you have the correct url.  For example here is the url to the sandbox test environment.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
. . . 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not behind any proxy server.If your using any software like hotspot it not allow to redirect to payment page.